# How does a website and android app connects?

Tags: java, android, database

I am new in android development and i have been developing android apps using cloud firebase but how can i make an app for a website which is not using firebase. I know i need to connect to its database but what if the website is hosted on wordpress.com which does not provide phpmyadmin. So is there any other way? I know there is something called rest api. Can we use rest api in websites that are developed in some framework like codeignitor? Please explain what rest api is and is there any other way to get the data for our app? Please let me know thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Unfortunately your question is an open ended question which would require thousands of words to answer. SO is more suited to specific programming Q&A format questions. I'd advise you ask this question on a forum or subreddit. Flagging to close.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be tough. Usually, an application communicate with a web service. A web service may be a **Rest API**, **Firebase** or any *hosted* service that can *provide data* (I don't know all of the subtilities of it).

Explaining to you how all of this works wouldn't work here as it will be objective as every application have different needs and every developper have preferences on how he want his application to communicate with the world.

One thing you should avoid at all costs would be to access an online database directly from your application as it is a huge security flaw.
Here are some links that will help you understand better all of this.

[REST API concepts and examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YcW25PHnAA)

[Make an HTTP request with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-an-http-request-with-android)

[Web services explained](https://www.service-architecture.com/articles/web-services/web_services_explained.html)

I am well aware that stackoverflow answer shouldn't be mainly links but I still thinks that they will be relevant to your problem. Be aware that this answer doesn't even cover a little part of communication between an application an a webservice. You'll have to learn that by yourself, using courses and tutorials.